# keeping checkbox checked if a value from another row is specificated

Tags: php, jquery

How to keep the checkbox button checked if a value from a row is 1?
My checkbox has an action with it :

```
  <input type="checkbox"  name="optradio" OnClick="doAction(<?php echo $id;?>);" >
```

and the ajax:

```
 function doAction(id){
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "example.php",
      data: "id=" + id,
      success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               }
 });
 }
```

If the value from the row id is 1 how can I keep the checkbox checked? Always?

Comment: Where is that value come from? Response from ajax call?

Comment: @Adiiia try my solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have already `$i` value then you can check like this

```
<?php
 $i = 1;// if $i =0; then `checkbox` is not selected
$check = $i == 1 ? 'checked' : '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" <?php echo $check ;?>>male
```